# dplyr define a temporary variable in mutate function

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with dplyr package of R.
Let's say I have a data frame of names and ids

```
   df <- data.frame(dID=c(1  ,2  , 1 ),
                   name=c("a","a","b"))
```

and I want to resolve each id from another database and get the information I need.

```
   db <- data.frame(dID=c(1   ,2   ,3   ,4   ),
                  info1=c("A" ,"B" ,"C" ,"D" ),
                  info2=c("AA","BB","CC","DD"))
```

Currently, I am using the following code.

```
   df %>% rowwise() %>%
   mutate(INFO1 = (function(id){paste(db %>% filter(dID == id) %>% select(info1))})(dID),
          INFO2 = (function(id){paste(db %>% filter(dID == id) %>% select(info2))})(dID))
```

I was wondering is it possible to find a solution to avoid repeating this part of the code

```
db %>% filter(dID == id)
```

by storing it in a temporary variable. For example when I, change my code to

```
df %>% rowwise() %>%
   mutate(tmp <- db %>% filter(dID == dID),
         INFO1 = paste(tmp %>% select(info1)),
         INFO2 = paste(tmp %>% select(info2))
)
```

I get this error

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Column `tmp <- db %>% filter(dID == dID)` is of unsupported class data.frame

Is there any way to make the code tidier and faster?

Comment: Are you sure you need the function call? To me it looks like you could just do `df %>% left_join(db, by = "dID")`.

Comment: @Marius I like your solution

Comment: @RonakShah the output is in answer 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Marius' comment. To demonstrate, the following reproduces the result from your `rowwise` `dplyr` chain

```
left_join(df, db) %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("info")), ~as.numeric(as.factor(.x)))
#  dID name info1 info2
#1   1    a     1     1
#2   2    a     2     2
#3   1    b     1     1
```